# Passing a string array to a function in C

Tags: c

I am just learning C, Could someone explain why the following code produces a Segmentation fault after printing the first element of an array?

what would working code look like?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ELEMENTS 8

void make(char ***array) {

*array = malloc(ELEMENTS * sizeof(char *));


    (*array)[0] = "test0";
    (*array)[1] = "test1";
    (*array)[2] = "test2";
    (*array)[3] = "test3";
    (*array)[4] = "test4";
    (*array)[5] = "test5";
    (*array)[6] = "test6";
    (*array)[7] = "test7";
    (*array)[8] = "test8";

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
char **array;
make(&array);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    free(array[i]);
}
free(array);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Actually, you need to read a lot about punters, just google it, you'll information to get fun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put a literal string in C++ like `"test0"`, it is actually stored in a special memory location where it cannot be modified. In the line

```
(*array)[0] = "test0";
```

you're pointing your `char*` to that memory location, which is alright to do. However, later, when you call `free(array[i]);`, you are attempting to free the same memory, which is a no-no. In general, only use `free()` if you have previously used `malloc()` on the same variable.

Also, as others have said, you need to allocate an array of size 9, since you're using 9 elements.

Answer (score 6):

1. Your array size is `8`, but you access index `8`, which is one past the end of your array. Count the number of elements if you don't understand...
2. You call `free` on the assigned string constants. Don't do this. Only `free` what you `malloc`, which is just `array`, not `array[0]` to `array[8]`.