# Modifying a string array inside of a function

Tags: c, c-strings

The following code example, doesn't print the strings `test1` - `test5` contained in `array` in the `main() function`

however it works inside the `make() function`

I am certain the answer is simple, how would I produce the desired result?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ELEMENTS 4

void make(char ***array) {

char p2[] = "test1 test2 test3 test4 test5";
char* token = strtok(p2, " ");
int i = 0;
while (token) 
{

    (*array)[i]= token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
}

printf("%s\n",(*array)[0]);
printf("%s\n",(*array)[1]);
printf("%s\n",(*array)[2]);
printf("%s\n",(*array)[3]);
printf("%s\n",(*array)[4]);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char **array;
make(&array);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

This code compiles without error or warning and produces the following output:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
yf�


���
```

my expected result was to have `test1 - test5` printed twice, once inside the `make() function` and once in the `main() function`

as a side note, this is only my second post to stackoverflow, this is modified code from my first question [Passing a string array to a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835300/passing-a-string-array-to-a-function-in-c)

Comment: You are still making your arrays too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char p2[] = "test1 test2 test3 test4 test5";
```

defines the string p2 on the stack of `make()` function. `strtok()` only returns pointers to the same array, which becomes invalid when `make()` returns.

It's the same as this:

```
char * foo()
{
    char array[] = "hello";
    printf("%s\n", array); // works fine
    return array;
}

void main()
{
    char * array = foo(); // just a pointer to invalid data
    printf("%s\n", array); // FAIL
}
```

## How to do it correctly

There are basically two ways to return strings in C.

Either by filling in a buffer:

```
void fill_buf(char * buf, size_t len)
{
    char string[] = "hello";
    snprintf(buf, len, "%s", string);
}

void main()
{
    char buffer[25];
    fill_buf(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Or by returning malloc'd string:

```
char * get_malloced_or_null()
{
    char my_string[] = "hello";
    char * copied_pointer = strdup(my_string); // might fail and return NULL
    return copied_pointer;
}

void main()
{
    char * string = get_malloced_or_null();
    if (string == NULL) { return; }
    printf("%s\n", string);
    free(string);
}
```

The advantage of the second approach is that you can use it with arbitrarily long strings. On the other hand, you need to check for allocation failures, and you have to free memory after you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `make()` function, you are parsing a **local** variable. As such, the `strtok()` returns stack address (and you array will reference a content in the stack that could be overwritten any time). Once the function `make()` is completed, those pointers will refer to anything in your stack and your array content may be any thing.

You may fix this as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ELEMENTS 4

void make(char ***array)
{
    char p2[] = "test1 test2 test3 test4 test5";
    char* token = strtok(p2, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while (token) 
    {
        (*array)[i]= strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s\n",(*array)[0]);
    printf("%s\n",(*array)[1]);
    printf("%s\n",(*array)[2]);
    printf("%s\n",(*array)[3]);
    printf("%s\n",(*array)[4]);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **array;
    make(&array);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the above answer;

You have to allocate memory for the `char ***array` at the beginning the `make()` function

```
*array = malloc(ELEMENTS * sizeof(char *));
```

and `ELEMENTS` should be define as `5` and not as `4`

```
#define ELEMENTS 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with simply defining p2[] `static`:

```
static char p2[] = "test1 test2 test3 test4 test5";
```

also, `ELEMENTS` should be 5, and the declaration of `array` in `main` is a simple "pointer to pointer", it should be "array of pointers":

```
char *array[ELEMENTS];
```

then you'll get enough room for your 5 strings.

**EDIT**: working with an array of pointers simplfies the `make()` function:

```
void make(char **array) {
    static char p2[] = "test1 test2 test3 test4 test5";
    char *token = strtok(p2, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while (token) {
        array[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, array[i]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *array[ELEMENTS];
    make(array);
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's not the best approach to making actual software, since it will break if you use the the function more than once.

Comment: True, but why parse the same string multiple times.. Actual software should not do so :)

Comment: Yep, but I've seen cases where one function was used to parse different strings.

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles cleanly, and produces the desired result, Thanks to all that helped me understand pointers.
now i'll work on freeing the memory I allocated to the array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ELEMENTS 5

void make(char ***array) {

char p2[] = "test1 test2 test3 test4 test5";
char* token = strtok(p2, " ");
int i = 0;
while (token) 
{

    (*array)[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
    strcpy((*array)[i], token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
}

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char **array;
make(&array);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```